# Как создать джойстик для игры на андроид 2D? unity5

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Как создать джойстик для перемещения персонажа? Для игры на андроид 2D на unity5. В google нечего не нашёл, как и в Youtube. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы имеет в виду экранный джойстик для мобильной игры, то, вероятно плохо искали:

- В asset store есть уже [большое количество](https://assetstore.unity.com/search?q=joystick&k=joystick) готовых решений, в том числе бесплатных. В нем не должно быть большого количества не совместимых с Unity 5 скриптов или решений. А если и есть, то должно быть легко переписать.
- Если множество англо язычных туториалов. При этом знание языка большой роли не должно играть. Попробуйте, посмотреть, например, [этот туториал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGYObojmkO4)